# Kotlin: calling non-final in constructor

Tags: kotlin

## Kotlin: calling non-final in constructor

Есть набор классов, унаследованных от одного базового. Процесс инициализации у них у всех одинаков, но зависит от некоего константного параметра, значение которого у каждого класса своё.

```kotlin
abstract class Parent() {

    protected open val v = 0
    open fun getValue(): Int = 0

    init {
        val value = getValue()
        println("val = $v")
        println("func = $value")
    }
}

class First(): Parent() {
    override val v = 1
    override fun getValue(): Int = 1
}

class Second(): Parent() {
    override val v = 2
    override fun getValue(): Int = 2
}

fun main(args: Array<String>): Unit {
    val o: Parent = First()
    val t: Parent = Second()
}
```

Результат:

```
val = 0
func = 1
val = 0
func = 2
```

Через `val` не получается, так как на момент вызова родительского конструктора, унаследованные поля ещё не инициализированы.
С переопределением же методов всё работает, как надо.
Но IDE всё равно указывает на "Calling non-final function getValue in constructor".
Видимо, он опасается, что я могу в переопределённом методе начать работать с неинициализированными свойствами.

Вопрос: какие могут быть подводные камни, если я буду использовать в базовом конструкторе открытый метод, но всегда буду возвращать из него константу?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если просто возвращать константу, то проблем быть не должно, так как механизм перегрузки методов будет работать даже в конструкторе родительского класса. Но если метод начнёт зависеть от свойств дочерних классов, то тут уже будет баг или ошибка времени выполнения.

На самом деле не ясно, зачем вам тут вообще переопределение, можно сделать проще:

```
abstract class Parent(val v: Int = 0) {
    init {
        println("val = $v")
    }
}

class First() : Parent(1) 

class Second() : Parent(2)
```

https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/classes.html#derived-class-initialization-order